# Conditional anchor in Repeater <ItemTemplate>?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, pagination, repeater

I'm using a repeater to print out page selectors / pagination links for a blog. On the main view of the blog, the number 1 should not have a link around it (since the user is already on the main page and thus the initial set of results). If the user clicks a page link this adds a query string of `?page=#` where `#` is the page number. When that page loads, that number should now be the one that does not have a link around it. This is helpful so people can see what page they're on.

To give you a visual, here's the approved design:

[image]

Here is my markup for the Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptBlogPagination" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
              <a href="?page=<%# Container.DataItem %>">
                  <%# Container.DataItem %>
              </a>
          </li>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In either the markup or the code-behind, how do I first check the current request/query string and then conditionally wrap an anchor around the number? It looks like ternary statements / null coalescing is popular, but is that best practice? It doesn't even seem possible, but I gave it a try anyway, and really couldn't get it to work...

[image]

I also tried giving the `<li>` an ID an `runat="server"` but the code behind did not recognize it. I think elements inside of an `<ItemTemplate>` are not reachable.

Comment: Could you not use ASP.Net ***[DataPager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager(v=vs.110).aspx)*** Server Control?

Comment: @Win There is no reason. I haven't done this before, is DataPager the better way to go? Would it make this specific feature easier to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the answers provided worked so I ended up keeping all page numbers anchors, but adding a css class to ones that the user was currently viewing by making the color black instead of orange.

Answer (score 0):

You would anchor onto the `Repeater.ItemDataBound` event.  You can find additional information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
protected void Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{     
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
         // Your conditional logic would go here.
     }
}
```

An example of your conditional would be to instantiate on the `DataItem`.  So it would look something like:

```
((Example)e.Item.DataItem).PropertyInPoco == "Some Value"
```

Hopefully this clarifies for you.

Comment: I'm confused. Let's say this is the first page, there is no query string. How do I specify that the anchor should not be included in the markup? Is it possible to get at the markup from the ItemDataBound event?

Comment: Every time your repeater executes, it will hit the event.  So you would do your comparison there.  Depending on the page, the postback will signify the Query String.  So I'm not sure what your confused about.